# Download URL File from Direct Download URL? | C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

So basically i'm trying to Download a File from a URL (NOT FROM A HTML/PHP) from a direct download link, example: https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/0/0/file.txt. I want my program to download a certain file from a direct download link in the same directory where the application was ran, i know this is possible in C# using [WebClient.DownloadFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.downloadfile?view=net-5.0) but I'm not exactly sure on how to use something similar in C++. If you could help that would be amazing, thank you and have a great day.

Comment: You need an HTTP library. C++ doesn't do this as part of the Standard Library.

Comment: You can use `libcurl` to achieve this.

Comment: Since you mention Visual Studio, you are probably running your program on Windows, yes? Windows has a [`URLDownloadToFile()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/ms775123(v=vs.85)) function. Or you can use Windows' WinInet API instead, see [HTTP Sessions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wininet/http-sessions) for details. Or, like others have stated, just use 3rd party HTTP libraries, like [libcurl](https://curl.se/libcurl/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, you could use [URLDownloadToFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/ms775123(v=vs.85)) to download files from the url.

I opened the link you gave but the webpage reported an error and did not find any txt. Therefore, you could refer to the following example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <urlmon.h>
#pragma comment(lib,"urlmon.lib")

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    HRESULT hr = URLDownloadToFile(0, L"http://pic104.nipic.com/file/20160715/6171480_185807154956_2.jpg", L"D:\\testfolder\\sky.jpg", 0, NULL);
    if (hr == S_OK)
    {
        cout << "ok" << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Of course, you could use the third-party library, such as `libcurl`.